# Only the icon in recycleview cell is clickable

Tags: android, event-handling, android-recyclerview

I checked out various examples of how to make a clickable RecyclerView and create one where each row has an icon on the left and two text labels stack on each other on the right, but I can only trigger the click handler if I click on the icon. I want to be able to click anywhere in the row. What do I do wrong in this code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/record_list"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/list_content"/>

<!-- list content -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_icon"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_type"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_below="@id/desc"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textStyle="italic"/>
</RelativeLayout>

    public class SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter
            extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private final List<Record> mValues;

        public SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Record> items) {
            mValues = items;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_content, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            Record record = mValues.get(position);
            holder.mIcon.setImageResource(record.iconRes);
            holder.mDescText.setText(record.desc);
            holder.mDetailText.setText(record.detail);
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Context context = v.getContext();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public final ImageView mIcon;
            public final TextView mDescText;
            public final TextView mDetailText;

            public ViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                mIcon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                mDescText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);
                mDetailText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail);
            }
        }
}
```

**UPDATED**

When I click at the row, I see the logcat logs the lines below

```
I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
```

So something is responding, but it is not the itemView and itemView has no parent.

Answer (score 2):

Try to handling click event of root element of your list content. 
In your case it would be RelativeLayout.

**Your list content would be as below.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rootLay"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/desc"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/icon"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:textIsSelectable="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_type"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/desc"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/icon"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:textStyle="italic" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**and your adapter file will be as below.**

```
public class SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<Record> mValues;

    public SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Record> items) {
        mValues = items;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_content, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Record record = mValues.get(position);
        holder.mIcon.setImageResource(record.iconRes);
        holder.mDescText.setText(record.desc);
        holder.mDetailText.setText(record.detail);
        /*holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context = v.getContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });*/

        holder.mRootLay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context = v.getContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final ImageView mIcon;
        public final TextView mDescText;
        public final TextView mDetailText;
        public final RelativeLayout mRootLay;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mIcon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            mDescText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            mDetailText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail);
            mRootLay = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rootLay);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried implementing recyclerviewItem click event?

Comment: Check this link. http://sapandiwakar.in/recycler-view-item-click-handler/

Comment: @AmitThakkar the item click handler works! Essentially we need to listen to the touch event from the recycler view!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
   <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:clickable="true"
         android:id="@+id/rel_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_icon"/>
            .
            .
            .
        </RelativeLayout>
```

In Adapter

```
        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final ImageView mIcon;
        public final TextView mDescText;
        public final TextView mDetailText;
        public final RelativeLayout rel_main;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mIcon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            mDescText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            mDetailText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail);
            rel_main = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rel_main);
        }
    }

      holder.rel_main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context = v.getContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Implement this code**

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

public interface OnItemClickListener {
     void onItemClick(View view, int position);
     void onItemLongClick(View view, int position);
}

private OnItemClickListener mListener;
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;

    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            View childView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

            if (childView != null && mListener != null) {
                mListener.onItemLongClick(childView, recyclerView.getChildPosition(childView));
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildPosition(childView));
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}
```

}

Set this listener to Recylerview

```
 recylerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(YourActivity.this,
                recylerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

             //Do your changes here

            }

            @Override
            public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));
```

Hope this will help!!!